# Does acceleration or deceleration affect the strength of impact if velocity is the same?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity, collision

2 identical cars both hit a wall at the same exact speed (let's say 50 mph), but one car was speeding up to 50 mph and the other car was slowing down to 50 mph. Also let's assume that the cars are just moving blocks with wheels since we only care about what happens outside the car.

Would this influence how much "damage" the wall takes at the exact point of impact?

Comment: In pure Newtonian theory, only thing that matters is the speed on impact, equivalent with kinetic energy. If you sit in a car hitting a wall, the bumper will take some fraction of time so the *exact* outcome might differ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The acceleration will not matter.  What will matter is the momentum of the car, which is entirely defined by velocity, not acceleration, and energy of the car, which is entirely defined by the velocity, not acceleration.

Now this is true for your "moving blocks with wheels" situation.  In a real setting, there might be second order effects because you have loaded down some of the mechanical components differently.  Given that acceleration and deceleration are caused by the wheels touching the road, acceleration causes the car to rotate, raising it higher on the front shocks and springs and lower on the rear shocks and springs.  Deceleration causes it to rotate the opposite way.  This can cause the vehicle to impact the wall differently, and that could change the results.

Comment: Another 2nd-order effect is that the driver is likely going to be positioned differently in the accelerating vs. decelerating case, which would certainly modify the impact damage to **them**.

Comment: Good point, @TimW. Presumably, both drivers are wearing seatbelts...

Answer (score 0):

@Cort Ammon, Also the Accelerometers in the SRS are directional and have tiny floating masses. The slowing Car has a preload on the forward crash sensor, towards activation. Where the Acceleration Car has a reverse preload on the forward crash sensor, against activation, even more than a steady speed car.   So the airbag system will read the front impact faster in the decelerating car, than a constant speed car, and an accelerating car is slower yet.

Conversely
Also consider all the free-to-move mass in the car. If we suppose that 'Damage' to a 'Car' is worse with one hard impact, than two equivalent impacts.
An accelerating car has all its 'loose' masses forced to the rear (Gasoline in a non-full Tank, foam rubber of the seats, change in the dash, fuzzy dice hanging from the mirror, etc). So then at impact these loose masses, are able to move and maintain their momentum, which is not used in the initial 'crash' of the car. Its not until they reach the end of their travel does there momentum get converted into the impact.  This is not the case in the de-accelerating car as all movable masses are already hard to the front and have no travel at time of impact.

Comment: I too low of rep to post as a comment to an answer that isn't mine, so I had to do one of those add-on answers